# How can I can delete/move/upload files within File Explorer? | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I've got a selenium webscraper and I need for it to be able to access my file explorer directories and files. I want to essentially upload images from the file explorer to a website I've got opened up. But I don't know where to even begin. I've looked at the Windows API, the File System Access API, as well as the os module. I'm confused as to which one has the functionality I mentioned, if any of them. I'm working with Python at the moment, but I'm open to alternatives in other languages. If you can point me to anything that can help I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not control the windows interface (or file explorer) what you can do is locate the element in your website that receives the filepath for that which you wish to upload and send the path using send_keys(filepath).

Comment: can't believe didn't think of that facepalm*. Thank you my friend!